# Яндекс блок «Поделиться» не появляется на странице

Tags: javascript, html, ya-share2

Как заставить блок «Поделиться» подгружаться внутри `<script></script>`?

### Работает:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,gplus,linkedin"></div>
```

### Не работает:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script type="text/html">
    <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,gplus,linkedin"></div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В клубе пользователей "Поделиться" [подсказали](https://yandex.ru/blog/share/5798978d8d94dc0016896bd6), как решить мою проблему. Цитирую:

> Вызов Ya.share2() нужно отложить до того момента, пока шаблонизатор не
>   поместит содержимое тэга script в документ.

Вот так это работает:

```
<script type="text/html">
    <div id='ya'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var share = Ya.share2('ya', {
            theme: { services: 'vkontakte,facebook,gplus,linkedin' },
            content: { url: 'example.com' }
        });
    </script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется, внутри блока `<script>` ожидается корректный JavaScript, но никак не HTML.

Вам нужно использовать [API блока для JavaScript](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/):

```
var share = Ya.share2('id-элемента', {
    theme: { services: 'vkontakte,facebook,gplus,linkedin' },
    content: { url: 'https://yandex.com' }
});
```

Comment: А можете написать работающий пример? У меня вот не получается http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxyOWK?editors=1000

Comment: Вы снова поместили HTML внутрь блока `<script>`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLKzOE

Comment: Да, так как у меня нет выбора. Мне необходимо разместить его внутри этого тега, так как весь шаблон обёрнут в него. А без <script> этот блок можно разместить ещё проще https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/ и всё будет работать.

Comment: Внутри тега `<script>` – только код, никакой верстки – это работать не будет.

Comment: Неправда. Вот пруфы:  http://javascript.ru/tutorial/foundation/start#vneshnie-skripty 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13886294/5381547

Comment: Первый – не пруф. Второй говорит лишь о том, что вы можете положить в тег любой контент, но в разметку он добавлен не будет, что хорошо показывает ваш же пример на CodePen.